# How do you access Vue-Composition-API type refs & "data" within Jest tests?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, vue-test-utils, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm currently working on a legacy Vue project.  We're using Vue 2.x w/ Typescript, with the Options API.

I'd like to make the case to switch to the Vue Component API, and so far I think it's a really compelling case - except for one drawback.

And that is - our existing tests fail.  Specifically, this is because of two reasons:

1. Tests that use mount() from '@vue/testUtils' can't use the .setData() method to set data manually (since the observable state is returned from setup(), and no longer lives in data);

Example:

```js
// FIXME: This test fails because Vue Test Utils .setData does not work
// with the new composition API.
it("renders by default", async () => {
  await wrapper.setData({
    crosshairCoordinates: [{ x: 0, y: 0 }],
  });
  expect(wrapper.findAllComponents(ChartTooltip).length)
    .toBe(1); // -> expected 1, recieved: 0
});
```

2. Tests that access a component or HTML element in the dom via findComponent() and a ref string no longer find the new style Refs

```js
// FIXME: This test fails because Vue Test Utils findComponent doesn't work
// with the way Refs are handled with the Vue Composition API.
it("should be default and not emit event on mouse move", async () => {
  const chartWrapper = wrapper.findComponent({ ref: "wrapper" });
  chartWrapper.trigger("mousemove"); // -> TypeError Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined
  expect(wrapper.emitted("mousemove")).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Quite frankly, if I can figure out how to resolve these issues, I can make a full recommendation to move to the VueComponentAPI and make some developers very happy. If I can't, then I can't recommend it and will have to stick with the Vue Options API.

Any ideas?

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils-next/issues/228

Answer (score 3):

1. instead of `wrapper.setData({foo: 'bar'})` you can use `wrapper.vm.foo = 'bar'`
2. i believe the behavior of `wrapper.findComponent()` did not change in any way. keep in mind that `wrapper.findComponent({ ref: "foo" })` [might return empty wrapper](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#findcomponent) if the ref is not a component but an html element

Answer (score 0):

I am new in Vue and I am already heading this issue. The answer looks like [there is no solution](https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils/issues/539)

What I got from this thread is that:

> setData only works with data. There isn't a good way to modify a value
> inside a function (like setup).
>
> For setup, I'd generally just recommend interacting with the component
> via trigger or passing props to test it (like a user would).

- [source](https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils/issues/539#issuecomment-822087284)

> There is probably some way to make it work using .vm, but this is not
> generally a good idea. vm is basically like a private variable - it's
> not something you can normally access in your application. Test Utils
> exposes it, but the majority of the time you don't need it.

- [source](https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils/issues/539#issuecomment-822151305)

> One option would just be to move these out of setup and allow them to
> receive arguments. You could make a composable

- [source](https://github.com/vuejs/test-utils/issues/539#issuecomment-823723356)